# Cargar Variable del Modelo desde JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

Tengo una Vista Razor C# en la cual tengo un boton.
Al hacer click en el boton capturo mediante JS su respectivo ID, lo que quiero es que ese ID obtenido, se cargue en un Atributo del Modelo actual, por ejemplo @Modelo.Id

mi boton:

```
< input type="button" name="pagin" value=@(i+1) id=@i onclick="return Pag(this)" />
```

metodo Js para el OnClick:

```
    function Pag(button) {
        alert(button.value);

        return false;
    }
```

lo que tengo dentro de alert, quiero cargarlo al modelo.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes tomar esto como base:

CSHTML (Vista principal):

@HtmlPartial("VistaParcila", Model)

CSHTML (Vista Parcial)

```
<input type="button" name="pagin" id="@i" onclick="Pag(@(i+1))" />
```

JS:

```
function Pag(value) {
        alert(value);
```

$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "tucontrolador/EstablecerPropiedad",
  data: { id: @id, nuevoId: value }
success: function(data){
$("contenedor").html(data);
}
})
}

Controlador:

```
public class TuControlador:Controller{

public ActionResult EstablecerPropiedad(int id, int nuevoId){
  var modelo = ObtenerModelo(id);  //Aca debes obtener tu modelo de tu origen de datos por medio de su id o algo similar

  modelo.Id = nuevoId;
  //Aca solo se ha asignado la propiedad, no se ha guardado en el origen de datos

  return PartiaView(modelo); //Esta vista ya tiene el modelo con el nuevo id
}
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: No entendiste la pregunta por lo visto, lo que quiero hacer es, cargar el value que mostras en alert, en un atributo del modelo. (@Modelo.Id) 

Sino lo que podria ser es cargar dicho ID capturado en un input hidden.

Comment: En MVC el modelo es de solo lectura del lado del cliente, si lo quieres modificar debes realizar una petición a un controlador que sea quien asigne el valor a la propiedad o atributo del modelo. Si no quieres recargar la pagina debes usar AJAX.

Comment: Podrias ayudarme con alguna guia de como usar AJAX en mi caso?

Comment: Ya edite la respuesta